# Send JSON Object while rendering a page with Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have an app written in `webapp2` using Google App Engine. The page I want to render needs to use some variables from the backend. How can I pass variables from Python to Javascript as a JSON object?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how Jinja2 relates and what you have tried?

Comment: I tried setting the `value` of the input tag to a value from Python using `{{name}}` which is Jinja's templating thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
//define your values dictionary

template_values = {"name": name,
               "other_value" : other values}

//render your template

template = jinja_environment.get_template("path to my html file")
return self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

then in your html you can use {{name}}

Answer (score 0):

In your template file, you'd need to do something like:

```
 <script>
        var your_js_object = {{your_json_dump}}
 </script>
```

This isn't ideal, as it means that `your_js_object` is global, but you'd have access to the object in your js files.